# Failed to set (heroID) user defined inspected property

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a problem with `Hero`, first I try to use `Hero` on my project and I can't make it works, then y try to make it works with the storyboard which is in Examples project but I get this error to.

```
Failed to set (heroID) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x100f1a700> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key heroID.
```

I don't know what to do:

```
IsHeroEnabled = On
```

[image: storyboard]

And `HeroID` is rigth.[image: storyboard2]

Please help me, I have read everything I could on the internet and I can not find a solution.

Comment: Check IBoutlet of herobutton & better to set it's class to UIButton

Comment: There is not a IBOutlet of herobutton & the class of the button is UIButton

Answer (score 0):

The Framework was not in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`
[image: caprute]

Normally when I put a framework in podfile and install pods it is automatically imported to this list.